# Create Mock class with values taken from a dictionary

Tags: python, mocking

I have a dictionary where keys are the same keys as a class that I want to mock.
How can I create a Mock class from this dict?

For example, let's say I have the class

```
class User:
  def __init__(self, amount, enabled):
    self.amount = amount
    self.enabled = enabled
```

Now, I would like to create a Mock

```
values1 = {amount: 1, enabled: False}
values2 = {amount: 2, enabled: True}

user_mock1 = MagicMock(spec=User)
user_mock2 = MagicMock(spec=User)
```

How can I create mocks, from the values of the dict?

I have a dict with lot of values, so I do not want to do this:

```
user_mock1.amount = values1['amount']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found they way, just do dict unpacking.

```
user_mock1 = MagicMock(**values1)

>>> pprint(vars(user_mock1))
{'_mock_call_args': None,
 '_mock_call_args_list': [],
 '_mock_call_count': 0,
 '_mock_called': False,
 'amount': 1,
 'enabled': False,
 'method_calls': []}
```

Comment: Remember to set the `spec` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. That is if you want to follow the spec of the mocked model. That I guess that most of the cases you would like to right? But not mandatory anyway

Comment: The alternative is you want the test double _not_ to follow the spec of the thing it's standing in for, which would make very little sense. Providing the spec means you get clear and immediate feedback when something tries to interact with the mock in a way that wouldn't work with the real implementation.